# TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, twitter, plot

I'm new to coding and am still learning. That being said, I've been following a tutorial on how to do data analysis from twitter API: http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/

I believe he's using python 2.7 while I am using python 3.6.1 so I have converted the code to the python version I am using and so far it has worked until I got to the top 5 countries graph.  Specifically, when I try to run the code for the top 5 countries which worked two days ago only once, now I only get the following error message:

```
"---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-47-601663476327> in <module>()
          7 ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
          8 ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
    ----> 9 tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
          10 plt.show()
~/Environments/Environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, kind, ax, figsize, use_index,   title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   2441                            colormap=colormap, table=table, yerr=yerr,
   2442                            xerr=xerr, label=label,  secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2443                            **kwds)
   2444     __call__.__doc__ = plot_series.__doc__
   2445 

~/Environments/Environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_series(data, kind, ax, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, label, secondary_y, **kwds)
   1882                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1883                  label=label, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 1884                  **kwds)
   1885 
   1886 

~/Environments/Environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1682         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1683 
-> 1684     plot_obj.generate()
   1685     plot_obj.draw()
   1686     return plot_obj.result

~/Environments/Environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in generate(self)
    236     def generate(self):
    237         self._args_adjust()
--> 238         self._compute_plot_data()
    239         self._setup_subplots()
    240         self._make_plot()

~/Environments/Environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    345         if is_empty:
    346             raise TypeError('Empty {0!r}: no numeric data to '
--> 347                             'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
    348 
    349         self.data = numeric_data

    TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot"
```

Has anyone else encountered this and/or what's the best solution? I can't figure out how to fix this. Thank you!

**Entire Code (to date)**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tweets_data_path = '...twitter_data.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

print (len (tweets_data))

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data))
tweets['lang'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data))
tweets['country'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['place']['country'] if     tweet['place'] != None else None, tweets_data))
```

## graph by top 5 languages

```
tweets_by_lang = tweets['lang'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Languages', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 languages', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_lang[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='red')
plt.show()
```

## graph by top 5 countries

```
tweets_by_country = tweets['country'].value_counts()

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=15)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Countries', fontsize=15)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of tweets' , fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Top 5 countries', fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
tweets_by_country[:5].plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your data actually numeric?   You can check using, for example,

```
print(type(tweets['country'][0]))
```

Given that you're using `json.loads` (deserializing from string) it's very likely NOT numeric, which is what the error might be referring to.  Try to convert the data type to float (or whatever):

```
tweets = tweets.astype('float')
```

and see if that solves the problem.  You can also apply this function just to specific columns if you want.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think your file isn't present or there is a path issue.
The first two steps  http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2014/07/twitter-analytics/ retrieves the file and saves it locally. 
Is the file present in the specified path ?

```
    tweets_data_path = '...twitter_data.txt'
```

What does the following return ?

```
    print (len (tweets_data))
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, the path is saved to my local drive. And the print (len(tweets_data)) returns 9 when I ran the twitter_streaming.py for about 5mins. So the chart for top 5 languages will work but not the top 5 countries. Would it be helpful to provide a screen print? Not sure if that's possible but I can try.

Comment: The data frame seems to be empty. Could you try print(head(tweets_by_country ))?

Comment: Also, could you add print(head(tweets)) and add that result to your question? Will really help!